# High Block Validation

Tags: synchronization, consensus, proof-of-work

Suppose node A is running on height 2000. Node B sends to node A block with height 2002. Node A is not able to validate the block without having a block with height 2001. How does node A behave in this case? Does it start synchronization, or just ignore the block 2002, or ..?